# Setting a Jenkins Pipeline timeout for only a group of stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I know that one can set a timeout for the entire pipeline script or a specific stage using `options`, but is there a way to set a timeout for a group of stages? For example a total 10 minute timeout (not 10 minute each) for only 3 out of the 5 stages, and let the other 2 run freely.

Comment: You can create a timeout per stage. You can also try a timeout for `stages { stage {...} stage {...}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can create nested stages and define the `timeout` option for the parent stage:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('Stage A') {
            options{
                timeout( time: 10, unit: 'SECONDS' )
            }
            stages {
                stage('Stage A1') {
                    steps { 
                        sleep( time: 4, unit: 'SECONDS' )
                    }
                }
                stage('Stage A2') {
                    steps { 
                        sleep( time: 4, unit: 'SECONDS' )
                    }
                }
                stage('Stage A3') {
                    steps { 
                        sleep( time: 4, unit: 'SECONDS' )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Stage A3 will never be executed because of the parent timeout. It will be marked as "aborted":

[image: Jenkins Pipeline]